# How to Iterate through a Stack of a Tuple of Tuples in Python

Tags: python, loops, search, stack, tuples

I am trying to implement a `DepthFirstSearch` algorithm in Python using a `Stack` class predefined as:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def push(self,item):
        self.list.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.list.pop()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return len(self.list) == 0
```

I also have function:

```
def isGoalState(self, state):
    isGoal = state == self.goal
```

that returns whether or not we are at the predefined goal state, 
function:

```
def getStartState(self):
    return self.startState
```

that returns the tuple `(int,int)`, the position of the Agent, 
and function:

```
def getSuccessors(self, state):
    self._expanded += 1
    return successors
```

which returns a tuple of tuples of all available next "moves" for the Agent in the form `((int,int),string,int)` where `(int,int)` is the state of the successor, `string` is the direction (NSEW), and `int` is the cost to the successor.

Here is what I have thus far for my implementation of a `GraphSearch` that implements `DepthFirstSearch`:

```
def depthFirstSearch(problem):
    closed = []
    fringe = util.Stack()
    fringe.push(problem)

    i = 0
    while not fringe.isEmpty():
        currentState = fringe.pop()
        print "current's successors:", currentState.getSuccessors(currentState.getStartState())

        if currentState.isGoalState(currentState.getStartState()):
            return currentState

        if not (currentState in closed):
            closed.append(currentState)
            print "closed now includes:", closed[i].getStartState()

            children = currentState.getSuccessors(currentState.getStartState())
            print "children:", children

            while not children.isEmpty():
               fringe.push(children.pop())

            print "fringe:" fringe

        i += 1
```

I realize this is not complete, and the problem comes when I am trying to iterate through temp in `for x in temp:`. I get through the first iteration and then am stopped the second time. Here is the terminal output:

```
current's successors: [((5, 4), 'South', 1), ((4, 5), 'West', 1)]
closed now includes: (5, 5)
children: [((5, 4), 'South', 1), ((4, 5), 'West', 1)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
...
...
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute isEmpty
```

So clearly I am not traversing through this list of tuples of tuples correctly to transfer them into the fringe as two added tuple of tuples.

Any ideas of how I should traverse with this specific implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getSuccessors` pops an element of the list and returns it. Elements in the list are not themselves instances of Stack, so they have no `isEmpty` method.

Note that DFS is usually implemented via recursion; you may find it easier to work out where you're going wrong if you do that.

Comment: What am I supposed to do with that information? The algorithm skeleton I am working from does not include recursion and can't because of its graphing

Comment: I now understand what you were getting at. Thanks for the help.